# symfony Illegal string offset 'name'

Tags: php, symfony, web, doctrine

i get this error in almost all the commands i do with the symfony app/console

> E:\personal_data\programming_projects\Web\horecareport>php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>     Warning: Illegal string offset 'name'
>
> doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [-f|--force] [--em [EM]]

i'm working on somebody else's code, and i'm trying to do a self referencing on an entity and it looks something like this:

```
`manyToOne:
    productGroupParentid:
        targetEntity: ProductGroup
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        inversedBy: ProductGroup
        joinColumns:
            product_group_parentid:
                referencedColumnName: product_group_id
        orphanRemoval: false
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }`
```

but it says :
ProductGroup#productGroupParentid refers to the inverse side field which does not exist.

i checked the symfony documentation i contain something like that

`joinColumn:
   name: category_id
   referencedColumnName: id`

but when i added that `name : product_group_parentid` the problem started to happen

Comment: This does not have to be a bug, you might have coded sth that can't be interpreted by the YamlDriver. Think about your code, did you wrote sth. which contains a var "name"?

Comment: show your schema

Comment: i edited the post thanks you for the response